# return HashMap as the result in Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I have a table department which has department_id as id column and employee name
under employee column. I need to return a HashMap with departId as the key and number of employees
of the department as the value. I wrote this code below in mybatis

In Deptmapper.xml I have

```
<select id="getAll” resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT id as dept_id,count(employee) as headCount
    FROM department
</select>
```

In Deptmapper.java I have

```
Void getAll(ResultHandler handler);
```

In DeptmapperDAO.java

```
public Map<Integer,Integer> getAll() {

    HashMapResultHandler resultHandler= new HashMapResultHandler();
    deptmapper. getAll(resultHandler);
    return resultHandler.getMap();
}
```

In HashMapResultHandler.java I have

```
public class HashMapResultHandler implements ResultHandler{

    private Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext resultContext) {

        HashMap<String,Object> resultObject = (HashMap<String,Object>) resultContext.getResultObject();
        System.out.println("resultObject   ---> "+resultObject.keySet());
         map.put(Integer.valueOf((String)resultObject.get("dept_id")),Integer.valueOf((String)resultObject.get(“head_count")));

    }

    public Map<Integer,Integer> getMap(){
        return map;
    }
}
```

When I debug this code. I’m always getting `resultContext.getResultObject();`  as Null. Any idea what I’m missing?

Comment: Does the query itself work for you? It doesn't look like correct sql query. If it does work what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: indeed, the GROUP BY clause is missing

Comment: I guess this has be re typed in, it is not copy of working code.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I found the answer for this posting it here, so that, it can help others. The issue was <setting name="autoMappingBehavior" value="NONE"/>  I changed it to PARTIAL and it worked fine. If we have NONE then we should define the resultMap.